# Crystal Report return values for the last week

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to filter a report to return all the data for the last week so that I can send a report to staff for there records for the week.

I have in the past used the same concept to return all records for yesterday.  See code below:

```
if {vwtb_Audit.AUDIT_DATE} = currentdate -1 then "Yesterday"

Else

"Other"
```

if i use this code I will only return things for 7days ago and it won't allow me to return the other data from the other days in the week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{vwtb_Audit.AUDIT_DATE} in Last7days
```

includes today

```
{vwtb_Audit.AUDIT_DATE} in lastfullweek
```

includes last week from Sunday to Saturday

```
(
{vwtb_Audit.AUDIT_DATE} >= minimum(lastfullweek) + 1
and
{vwtb_Audit.AUDIT_DATE} <= maximum(lastfullweek) + 1
)
```

includes last week from Monday to Sunday

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to a formula which I can then do a select records on.

```
if {vwtb_Audit.AUDIT_DATE} > dateadd ('d',-7,currentdate) then "lastweek"
else
"other"
```

and this returned all records from "last week"